# Buttons on PS4 Controller not Detected by Steam Controller Settings

Tags: steam, controllers

I am attempting to set up my PS4 controller on Steam PC and there are numerous button inputs not being detected. At the very least Steam does detect the controller, but when I try to set up the input layout as it requests, it does not detect the PS, center button (As shown equivalently in this picture):

[image]

Plus it does not detect any inputs from my right joystick (Movement in X and Y and Z [button press]), nor does it detect any inputs in the horizontal (x) direction or button press, (Z) direction of the left joystick. This is a brand new controller and I actually did get it to work for one game before in its entirety. However, when it did work before, I didn't have to manually input the layout and Steam didn't have any issues with it. It was disconnected once from my PC and then upon re-connection it began throwing this fit. I have already tried the following:

1. Turning off PlayStation configuration support
2. Restarting Steam and PC
3. Resetting PS4 controller